# Why does PyTorch use a different formula for the cross-entropy?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, objective-functions, pytorch, cross-entropy

In my understanding, the formula to calculate the cross-entropy is

$$
H(p,q) = - \sum p_i \log(q_i)
$$

But in PyTorch `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` is calculated using this formula:

$$
loss = -\log\left( \frac{\exp(x[class])}{\sum_j \exp(x_j)} \right)
$$

that I think it only addresses the $\log(q_i)$ part in the first formula.

Why does PyTorch use a different formula for the cross-entropy?

Comment: You are using the Softmax CE loss, use BCE loss or Binary CE loss for your formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you one-hot-encode your labels with $p_i \in \{0,1\}$ you get $p_i = 0$ iff $i$ is not correct and, equivalently, $p_i =1$ iff $i$ is correct.

Hence, $p_i \log(q_i) = 0 \log(q_i) = 0 $ for all classes except the "truth" and $p_i \log(q_i) = 1 \log(q_i) = \log(q_i) $ for the correct prediction.

Therefore, your loss reduces to:
$$
H(p,q) = - \sum p_i \log(q_i) = - \log(q_{truth})
$$

Comment: I'm not sure whether OP wanted to know this.

Comment: @DuttaA have a look at the last part of the question: "that I think it only addresses the $\log(q_i)$ part in the first formula. So is that means Pytorch using different Cross entropy formula?". Reads to me that it actually is exactly about this. .

Comment: OMG! yes, this is what I meant, I accidentally mix language modeling cross-entropy (that have continuous values of $p_i$) and PyTorch `nn.CrossEntropyLoss`. I forgot in classification $p_i$ will be 0 or 1 so the PyTorch function is valid, but of course, I can't use it directly for Language Modeling case. Thank You!

Comment: @Sammy This answer partially answers the question, but I think you should also explain the function inside the log (in the PyTorch version). What function is that? Note that I know what function that is, but, for completeness, I think you should also explain it. Maybe you should also refer to the documentation. Afterward, I will upvote your answer ;)